# How to increase Visual Studio Code cursor height?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, ide, editor

I need to increase the height of Visual studio `Cursor |`. I feel that will give better flow to writing code. Sublime text have the option, but I can't find that for Visual studio code. Can any one help to do that please?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try and apply the pending [PR 28109](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/28109) "support custom cursor height".

It does resolve [Microsoft/vscode issue 27931](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/27931): "Configure cursor height"

> Using the `caret_extra_*` properties in Sublime and with css in Atom, it is possible to configure the height of the cursor.
>   I would love to be able to make the cursor a little bit taller.
>   Is this possible with VSCode?